# Stop function as soon as variable is false

Tags: javascript, function, return

**Note:**

The actual function works with async. During the code execution await is used several times. The execution of the actual function takes about 20 seconds. The actual function is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/JueK3y/Instagram-automated-commenting/blob/main/Rework/public/src/js/mainApp.js).

**The idea:**

The function `func` is executed as soon as variable `specVar` is True. If at any time during this execution `specVar` becomes False, the whole function should be "aborted" or stopped.

**The problem:**

I already tried to put the function into a while loop (`while(specVar{}`) of the function continues to be executed, even if the while loop should actually stop (`specVar = False`).

Now I put an if query before every single "function point" to check if `specVar` is still True. However, the more complex the function becomes, the more effort it takes to include this query.

**The current code**

```
let specVar

document.getElementById("funcStart").onclick = () => {
    specVar = true
    func()
}
document.getElementById("funcStop").onclick = () => { specVar = false }

function func() {
    console.log("Function starts")
    // Some code...
    if (specVar) console.log("Function still running, 1")
    else return
    // Some code...
    
    if (specVar) console.log("Function still running, 2")
    else return
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So func() is supposed to keep running? you need to use setInterval or setTimeout

Comment: Is your func() run in intervals of *N* milliseconds? Is it a long-running function embodying many `await`s? (clearly not since the missing `async`...)

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded.  How is `specVar` going to change while `func` is executing, before it completes?  Maybe the example shown doesn't really demonstrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: Your question is unclear. More like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which misses to explain what you're actually needing this for - presenting an unrelated sample code.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You're right, it is. Providing the full code would go beyond the scope of this post. If you want to see the full code, i can give you the GitHub URL

Comment: @epascarello No, func() should stop as soon specVar is false

Comment: Not sure how that would be possible with how threading works in JavaScript.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan My bad, the function is actually missing the async. During the execution of the code, await is used several times. I'm going to update the description, thanks for the hint

Comment: Maybe: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html ?